# ResultSet TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE equal feature in ado.net

Tags: datatable, ado.net, dataset

I am new to ado.net, i come up with a question, in java we have a option to show the update the result set continuously with **TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE** is there any such functionality exists in ado.net to update the data table when underlying table is updated?

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5938/how-to-refresh-the-data-in-grid-while-updating-a-record-in-underlaying-data-table